# accessing methods of a dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll

how to access the methods of a dll in .net using c#

Comment: possible duplicate of [DLL classes and their access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961394/dll-classes-and-their-access)

Comment: This is substantively the exact same question you asked before.  You just made it even less readable.  This is a very poor question and does not belong on SO.  Nor do you, if you keep asking questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Include the dll in your references folder in your project.

Here is a good article on doing that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what kind of Dll you are talking about. If you are talking about .Net Dll's, that is, .Net assemblies without an entry point, then Abe's answer applies. If you are talking about unmanaged/native DLL's written in C, you should use the Dllimport attribute in defined in System.Runtime.InteropServices namespcae. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28VS.71%29.aspx) link might help you.

Answer (score 0):

### .net

- load the Assembly using '[Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx)' or adding a reference
- use the Classes in the Assembly

### unmanaged

- Use [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)