# accessing functions or methods of the non .net dlls

Tags: c#

how to access the methods of non .net dll in .net in c#? which class is used to access the dll methods.

Comment: Is this question related to your earlier questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961394 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971660

Answer (score 3):

You do this with [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinvoke). An excellent resource is [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).

A simple example would be GetTickCount:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint GetTickCount();
```

Something more complex, MessageBox:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, int options);
```