# usercontrols in .net

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

When we place a usercontrols on a form in windowsform application , then how it is possible to get the form on which the user control is placed?

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: Edited the question for you and added some tags - perhaps you think about accepting some answers?

Comment: Not the first time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540117/accessing-functions-or-methods-of-the-non-net-dlls

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`ParentForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform.aspx) property:

> Gets the form that the container control is assigned to.